# New transaction is waiting for open operation sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I'm using this plugin : https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

I'm getting above issue in my project while doing DB transactions. Actually there so many transactions in my project at same time from js as well as java end.

Below is my code (just one query) :

```
function createTable(latWS,longWS,empId) {

        window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'test.db', location: 'default'}, function(db) {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (loc_emp_lat, loc_emp_long, loc_emp_accuracy, loc_emp_local_time)');
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('Open database ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
      });
        setTimeout(insertIntoLogTable(latWS,longWS,empId),500);
    }
```

I have checked, it is not going in error message.

I'm using version :
cordova-sqlite-storage 1.4.7 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"

My Cordova Android version is : 4.1.1

Comment: did you ever solve this? I too am getting new transaction is queued, waiting for open operation to finish

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) (which is based on [Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)) on Android.

The `createFromLocation` parameter was responsible for messing things up. Using only the `name` parameter is sufficient on both platforms.

This is what I'm using, on both Android and iOS:

```
SQLite.openDatabase({ name: "dbname.sqlite"});
```

On Android 7.0, the database will be saved to `/data/data/com.mypackage/databases/dbname.sqlite`.

Answer (score -2):

You need  to use a delay before creating table, example:

```
 window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'test.db', location: 'default'});

 setTimeout(function(){
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (loc_emp_lat, loc_emp_long, loc_emp_accuracy, loc_emp_local_time)');

},4000);
```

Comment: The problem remains even with a timeout.